# Android Global Search app replacement

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am working on an app that will be an alternative to the default Android search app. I want my app to be the default app that runs when the user presses (not long press) the hardware search button. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi. Have you managed to solve it yet? I have a similar problem and can't find any answer!

Answer (score 2):

There is an intent for that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEARCH

So basically you just need an app that listens to the intent and the rest is the choice of the user...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. After registering for the intent, hitting the search button still bring's up Google's Quick Search Box. After looking at the source for Android's GlobalSearch package, I see that the default app registers for a "android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" intent, but when I register for that it still doesn't work. I'm beginning to think it's impossible.